# Django ModelForm creating new instance instead of updating existing database entry

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form that works with a `Tool` object that is related to a single user.

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(BaseUser)
    tool_type = models.CharField(('tool_type'), max_length=40, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(('description'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField()
```

This tool is updated by this form

```
class ToolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tool_type = forms.CharField(max_length=40, label="Tool Type: ")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Description: ")
    available = forms.BooleanField(required = False)
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = BaseUser.objects.all(),
                                   widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Tool
```

The tool is made by this view

```
@login_required
def tool_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frm = ToolForm(request.POST)
        print(request.user)
        if frm.is_valid():
            frm.save()
            return render_to_response('tools/tool_register_success.html')
    else:
        frm = ToolForm(initial = {'owner':request.user})

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = frm
    args['activeuser'] = request.user

    return render_to_response('tools/tool_register.html', args)
```

And this is where the problem is. I'm updating the tool with this view.

```
@login_required
def tool_edit(request, tool_id):
    curr_tool = Tool.objects.get(pk = tool_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frm = ToolForm(request.POST, instance = curr_tool)
        if frm.is_valid():
            frm.save(force_update = True) 
            return render_to_response('tools/tool_edit_success.html')
    else:
        frm = ToolForm(instance = curr_tool)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = frm

    return render_to_response('tools/tool_edit.html', args)
```

But this **creates a brand new instance of the given tool with the updated information instead of updating the existing one**. Please note that I'm using the usual `instance = x`. The tool is related to a single `BaseUser`. If it matters, here is that code as well.

```
class BaseUser(AbstractUser):

    zipcode = models.IntegerField(('Zipcode'), max_length=5, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(('Address'), max_length=40, blank=True)
    shown_username = 'username'


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Base User'

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name',
                       'last_name',
                       'email',
                       'zipcode',
                       'address',
    ]
```

I'm a little lost. Every single thing I've read has said that this should be updating and not creating.

Why is it creating a new instance instead of updating my old instance? How can I fix the code so it will update my old instance?

Comment: AFAIK, `force_updaet=True` applies to `Model.save()` method, I'm not sure if `ModelForm.save()` method recognizes that keyword. I've checked this page, there is no mentioning of `force_update` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms

Comment: Are you sure you are posting to the right method? Can you show the template?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the form with `commit=False`, then commit/save the Model instance with `force_update=True` ?

This is how I suggest saving the Tool instance:

```
if frm.is_valid():
    tool = frm.save(commit=False)
    tool.save(force_update=True)
```